# Making accelerometer respond to double impacts (tapping it twice in the table)

Tags: double, accelerometer

I'm creating a simple application which does certain things depending on the accelerometer. At the moment it initiates the things if i move it in -z-direction fast enough. My goal is though to make it so that if i tap the phone in the table twice it will perform the tasks.
The phone is going to be orientated face up and therefor the back of the phone will "hit" the table twice. The settings I would want for it is so that if the "strong" enough taps in the table happen within one second it will perform the tasks. So the setting of one tap is not an issue but it is, for me, to make it only respond to it if it happens twice within the given timelimit.

Huge thanks before hand!

Comment: ooooh right in the table. poor phone.

Comment: What did you try? can we see some code?

Comment: @TimothyGroote supposed to be a light tap ;) and I haven't gotten anything that would make the doubletap work. Only if I tap it down once (which doesnt work to well since it also performs the tasks if I pull the phone upwards since the acc. when it slows down is also in -z-diretion)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the accelerometer you have you either have to sense two peaks within a reasonable, and separated by, the latency time interval, or you can get the hardware to detect a double pulse in the axis you wish. I'm looking at the spec of the MMA7455L, which can do double pulse. If you hardware doesn't do it, you can just sample the acceleration in measurement mode, or even easier set the device to level mode and wait for the interrupts on the threshold you specify.